# Apache Flink Partition (by Range) multiple times without sending data again

Tags: java, apache-flink, partition

I'm currently using Apache Flink for my master thesis and I have to partition it multiple times over an iteration.

I would like to have the same data on the same nodes while processing, but I don't know how I can do that. I think, Flink will always send the data again arbitrarily to the nodes.

Is there a possibility to call multiple times, e.g., partitionByHash(...) and have the data on the same node?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of transformation do you apply to the data? Operators (no keyBy) with the same parallelism will be chained together, processing the data on the same node.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand that. But does that mean, when I'm doing several times partitionByHash(...) and between the calls operations like map, reduceGroup, reduce and filter, that the same data, that was on the first partitionByHash on the one node will be on the same node on each consecutive partitionByHash? Hopefully you understand my question...